# Caching data in one Singleton class and using in another in Java

Tags: java, oop

I have a class which calls two singleton classes FirstClass and SecondClass as below. Is there a way to access the data computed in FirstClass in the SecondClass. In this case I don't want to make external service call in second class since the first class has already called it. Instead, just use the data (stored in first class function) in the second data function. What are the ways to do it.

```
public class CallingFunction() {
    List<String> generateData() {
    return Lists.newArrayList(new FirstClass(), new SecondClass())
}

@Singleton
public class FirstClass() extends interface {
    public String function() { 
    //operations. This function calls multiple services and stores ouput  to hashMap
    Map<String, String> hashedData = Maps.newHashMap();
    hashedData.put(dataFromAnotherService);
    return hashedData.get("abc");
    }
}

@Singleton
public class SecondClass() extends interface {
    public String function() { 
    //Use hashedData here instead of invoking the service again.
    //Other operations
    return "data";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve the functionality by something below logic:

```
@Singleton
public class FirstClass() extends interface {
    private static FirstClass instance;
    private Map<String, String> hashedData = new HashMap<>();
    public String function() { 
        //operations. This function calls multiple services and stores ouput  to hashMap

        hashedData.put(dataFromAnotherService);
        return hashedData.get("abc");
    }
    public Map<String, String> getHashedData() {
        return this.hashedData;
    }
    public static FirstClass getInstance() {
         if (instance == null) instance = new FirstClass();
         return instance;
    }
}

@Singleton
public class SecondClass() extends interface {
    public String function() { 
         FirstClass instance = FirstClass.getInstance();

         // instance.getHashedData() here instead of invoking the service again.
         //Other operations
         return "data";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Inject FirstClass into the constructor of SecondClass.

Comment: What difference will it make?

Comment: @tgdavies how does injecting Firstclass into the constructor of second class benefit from the above approach?